# What is the word to describe someone that loves a person despite his/her faults?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests

For example, a fan that adores his/her idol no matter what the idol does. Like the idol is just literally entering the stage and the fan screams hysterically.

Comment: **True lover**.

Comment: Presumably we all do.

Comment: You've correctly chosen the [single-word-requests] tag here, but please check out the [help available](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). The variety of answers so far emphasises the need to follow the question checklist, **especially** the requirement for a sample sentence with a blank in it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  New contributor. Clear definition of the problem. Variety of answers is not unusual here. Rather heavy-handed closure of question.

Comment: @Anton It's not a clear definition of the problem: that's the point. Each of the answers addresses a *possible* definition. We have that particular close reason for **exactly** this sort of question. If it's edited following the guidelines in the tag help, it can certainly be reopened.

Comment: @ AndrewLeach Agreed in principle, but a request for “the word to describe” is clearly asking for an adjective, not for phrases or idioms. An example sentence is certainly desirable but is implicit in the “for example” part of the question. Let us hope the questioner can comply with your advice.

Comment: @Anton - I would note that the connotations associated with this haven’t been provided- Should this be positive?  A true lover, devoted... or negative?  A sycophant, fanatic...  etc.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the idiom **warts and all**, which the *American Heritage Dictionary* defines as—

> All defects and imperfections notwithstanding:

*They love each other, **warts and all.***

Answer (score 1):

The expression ***[love is blind](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/love%20is%20blind)*** is generally used to express your concept:

> used to say that people do not see the faults of the people that they love

(M-W)

Answer (score 0):

I describe such people as

> Infatuated = having a strong but unreasonable feeling of love or attraction for someone or something
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/infatuated)

It is often used in constructions such as “The girl was infatuated with the pop star.”

According to Google ngram, “infatuated with” has been in steady use for the last century whereas “infatuated by” has shown a steady decline.